# Bootstrap 4 - How to change order on mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a responsive layout with Bootstrap 4 which consists of two columns. Both columns have a total of 9 divs, four on the first column, five on the second column. I'd like to change the orders of the divs inside the columns if the breakpoint is below LG.

Here's an explanation and the correct order I'd like to achieve:

[image]

What I currently have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="mb-4">
                left 1
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                left 2
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                left 3
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                left 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="mb-4">
                right 1
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                right 2
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                right 3
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                right 4
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                right 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Correct order"? I don't see the logic behind it. It seems random. This is not ideal for a responsive layout.

Comment: Look at the screenshot I provided, there's nothing random. Not ideal? Your statement nor your whole comment does make any sense.

Comment: You numbers in the code do not match the image...it's really unclear what it is you are trying to do... **but** you can't change the `order` between containers.

Comment: The numbers do match the image and there's only one container used as you can see in the code. smh

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do for me. You have `right 1` as text in the code and `order = 1` on your image, are these the same boxes? If so you can't do it since you can't change the order between containers (as previously said) Don't mix container (=== a div) with a div which has a class `container`

Answer (score 4):

Visual order of columns can be changed in Bootstrap 4 since it uses flex box .The responsive [**ordering classes using flex**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) can be used.
 And we can specify order to differently to each viewports.
 Using order-xs-12,order-sm-2,order-md-0, order-lg-5, order-xl-last.We can specify order of columns from 0-12,order-first and order-last for first and last column.

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column ">
     <div class="mb-4">
     left 1
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4 bg-info order-sm-last order-md-first order-lg-last ">
     left 2
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4">
     left 3
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4">
     left 4
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column">
     <div class="mb-4">
     right 1
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4">
     right 2
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4 bg-success order-lg-last order-md-first order-sm-
    first">                
     right 3
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4">
     right 4
     </div>
     <div class="mb-4">
     right 5
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**On Larger Screen**
[image: **On Larger Screen**]

**On Medium Screen**
[image: **On Medium Screen**]

**On Small Screen**
[image: **On Small Screen**]