# Ordering divs in mobile using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the order of divs only on mobile. So the divs should stay in the order that I put them in on desktop, but when the user transitions to mobile, the order should change. How do I do that using bootstrap?

Here's what I tried

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm order-sm-1">
A
</div>
<div class="col-sm order-sm-12">
B
</div>
</div>
```

what happens is that the order changes on desktop and on mobile. I only want the order to change on mobile. So on mobile, B should be above A. but on desktop, A should above B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 - How to change order on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848937/bootstrap-4-how-to-change-order-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, widescreen containers are displayed on the same line by making the value of the `flex-direction` style `row`. On mobile screen size, containers are displayed on different lines by assigning `column` to the value of the `flex-direction` style. A value is assigned to the `order` style for sorting the containers on the mobile screen size. I couldn't find any solution options directly using bootstrap styles.

[image]

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#firstContainer{
  order: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#secondContainer{
  order: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* The order of the containers is changed on the mobile browser screen. */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;         
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
 
 #firstContainer{
  order: 2; 
 }
 
 #secondContainer{
  order: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="col-6" id="firstContainer">A</div>
    <div class="col-6" id="secondContainer">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. B shows up first on desktop. I want B to show up second on desktop but show up first on mobile.

Comment: @PotaOnasys I have developed a new solution, I hope it will work for you.